# Bash associative dictionary not working (declare: -A: invalid option)

Tags: bash, macos, dictionary

I have followed each bash dictionary example, and none will work. I have now

_CONFIG:

```
#!/bin/bash


instance_map["dev"]=project-dev
instance_map+=( ["stage"]="project-staging" )

declare -A animals=( ["moo"]="cow" ["woof"]="dog")
```

test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

source _CONFIG


echo ${instance_map["dev"]}
echo ${instance_map["stage"]}


echo "${animals[moo]}"
for sound in "${!animals[@]}"; do echo "$sound - ${animals[$sound]}"; done
```

For some reason, after following each example, I get

```
$ ./test.sh dev
_CONFIG: line 9: declare: -A: invalid option
declare: usage: declare [-afFirtx] [-p] [name[=value] ...]
project-devproject-staging
project-devproject-staging
dog
0 - dog

$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.0(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0)
```

How do I map the user input 'dev' to 'myprojectname' in Bash?

Comment: You have installed second bash. but the script uses the default `/bin/bash`. (shebang). The default is 3.2 (doesn't knows the `-A`). when you type `bash --version` the PATH is searched and executed your brewed bash... change your shebang to `#!/usr/bin/env bash` or change the path for example `#!/usr/local/bin/bash`.

Comment: you can take my answer and I'll accept if you want

Comment: Just accept it yourself. You can accept your own answer :) :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was fixed by upgrading bash. `$BASH_VERSION` prints your true version

```
brew unlink bash
brew update && brew install bash
```

test.sh:

```
declare -A instance_map=( ["dev"]="project-dev" ["stage"]="project-staging" ["prod"]="project" )

echo ${instance_map["dev"]}
echo ${instance_map["stage"]}
```

Comment: I've updated to bash v5 and mine still does not work, `bash --version` shows bash is v5. Running test.sh as shown above produces: `-bash: declare: -A: invalid option
declare: usage: declare [-afFirtx] [-p] [name[=value] ...]`

Comment: @EricGreen you may have two versions of bash installed. `test.sh` is invoking `/bin/bash`, which may be different to what runs if you simply run `bash`. To see what you are running when you type `bash`, try `which bash`.